# How to implement animation into a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, animation, desktop-application, jframe

I am used to making web pages with animation using JQuery. I am now making a Java Desktop Application using Netbeans and Netbeans' Swing and without any animation it's looking pretty plain and boring.

- Are there any resources I can use for a guide to implement animation into my program?
- Does anyone have suggestions on what method to use?

Edit: I am not interested in something I'd have to buy.

Comment: What type of animations are you looking for?

Comment: What sort of animations are you after? 2D drawing on canvases? An animated L&F? Animated cursors? Something else entirely?

Comment: To get nice vizual effects and pretty GUI, you may try to use javafx (integrated into NetBeans IDE 6.9.1)

Comment: To quick startup with javafx you may google and glance this book http://www.amazon.com/JavaFX-Developers-Guide-Kim-Topley/dp/0321601653

Comment: @stemm Can JavaFX be used in combination with Netbeans Swing? I am using Swing. I probably should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @berry120 and @user489041 In general I'm looking for an animated Look and Feel.

Comment: @Dorothy Yes, since JavaFX 2.0 now it is a Java API, but it is still in beta.

Comment: @Dorothy yes, you might combine javafx and swing components in your java application, you're able to access to java objects directly from javafx, and, also, javafx compiles into jvm bytecode (in fact javafx components are swing-based)

Comment: @Dorothy you may visit http://javafx.com/

Comment: @stemm Thanks! Looks like JavaFX is the way to go. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Dorothy You're welcome :) If you'll have some troubles with javafx - you can ask new question, and I'll try to give more complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to stemm who pointed me in the right direction.

I decided to use JavaFX (JavaFX 2 to be exact)

Here is some resources I am using:

- http://download.oracle.com/javafx/
- http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/).  Both the principles and the framework code may be helpful to you.

Comment: I don't want something that I'd have to buy especially when I don't even know if it will be relevant for me at all.

Comment: +1, great recommendation. @Dorothy, that's one of the best resources around for animation in Java. if you're going to be cheap, then I'd recommend reading the [2D Graphics Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: In the "Links" section, you'll find a lot of information--articles, presentations, libraries, etc.--that will serve as an introduction.  You can also access the book's examples at the site.

Comment: You can have the source code and deduce the explanation. See the "examples" link.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a nice look and feel then [Substance](http://java.net/projects/substance/) might be a good way forward. It's not over-the-top animated or anything like that, but it's got a lot of skins and some in particular look very nice.